# Looking for TSA zipper parts

Tags: luggage

I have a suitcase onto which I'd like to apply a TSA-approved lock (as it's not having one).

I have bought a TSA-approved lock, and I would also need to replace the zipper's "car", in order to use this lock.

Now my options are very limited, as I couldn't really find suitable zippers.

My zipper is 8mm wide, and easily replacable.

The closest thing I could find is this:

[image]

But it's not available currently.

Do you have any good idea on where could I get these things (preferably online)?

Comment: You probably don’t need to replace the slider. You could just replace the pull tab, which gives you a lot more options. But locks on a zipper are mostly useless anyway.

Comment: @jcaron Not that TSA locks are worth anything anyway.

Comment: I feel this is an X Y problem. You can easily buy a full set of TSA masterkeys online, or 3D print your own. They present zero deterrent at all to theft. The effort you're going to here is not worthwhile. https://techcrunch.com/2016/07/27/security-experts-have-cloned-all-seven-tsa-master-keys/

Comment: The question tries to focus on "where can I buy the whole zipper car+puller". Besides comments has values in a way but not for the question itself.

Comment: @MJeffryes you could also just puncture the zipper with a simple pen and open the suitcase.